# Add type information during array destructing in a loop

Tags: typescript

Does typescript allow type annotations in `for...of` loops? Either something like this for array destructuring

```
for(let [id, value]: [string, number] of Object.entries(some_object)) { }
```

Or something like this for object destructuring:

```
for(let {a, b}: {a: string, b: number} of arr) { }
```

Note: Specifically asking about the case where `some_object` and `arr` either do not have type information or have incomplete type information.

Comment: Since you are using let, you can do `value = value as number` in the beginning of the body of the loop

Comment: @JuanMendes The reason I put it in a comment is because its not what the OP wants.

Comment: To the trigger happy downvoter: the OP clearly stated what they tried and what they are trying to achieve. Please leave a comment if you downvote a question or an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the correct types without a separate `let` in the body of the loop (as suggested by SharedRory), you can *fix* the type of the array you are iterating over by casting it.

```
const arr = [{a: 'a' as unknown, b: 2 as unknown}];

for(let {a, b} of arr) { 
    // No types in here b is unknown.
     a.b;
}

for(let {a, b} of arr as {a: string, b: number}[]) { 
    // Yes types here, a is a string
     a.replace("a", "");
}
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gbzgLhgcjn3ghgFcwBrMEAdzABoYAjPAJhPKpvoF8BdANwAoYQDMQCABQAbAKaxsTZrxggx8JAEoYmGMJiGYAemMwAciBhQAngAc5pAJZgYACzkI5Bo-AB0zCK8ohLS8opwyqrqmshwpNh40AguAObKeGBkALbMnrzo-Dp6PoamMACajtb21R5epYZwfl52MnDAclIARHDdTN3dWkHCQA)

Comment: Thank you, I like the solution of casting the second parameter in the `for...of` loop.

Comment: Thanks! This also seems to work with Object.entries as in:
`for(let [id, value] of Object.entries(myObject) as [id: string, value: MyValueClass]) { }`